# unhandled socket exception with no internet connection when i set timeout duration

Tags: flutter, dart, unhandled-exception, socketexception, timeoutexception

I use simple method to get some data from internet 'http get request' :

```
     `Future<UserModel> getUser(int userId) async {
       UserModel user;
       try {
            final response = await http.get(
             "$_baseUrl/users/$userId",
           )
             .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5))

            ;
         user = userModelFromJson(response.body);
       return user;
      } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
       print('$e in authentication service');
     throw e;
      } on SocketException catch (e) {
     print('$e in authentication service');
     throw e;
     } catch (e) {
     print('$e in authentication service');
    throw e;
      }
      }`
```

but when i have no internet connection it shows me that error :

```
 `Exception has occurred.
    SocketException (SocketException: Failed host lookup: 
    'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com' (OS Error: No address associated with 
    hostname, errno = 7))`
```

whenever i remove the .timeout(Duration(seconds:5)) the code works perfectly ,
but the socket exception is caught after long time (15-20)seconds to show that there is no internet connection that's why i used timeout, i tried to use multiple packages (http middleware ,http helper ,retry) , i tried to use http.client and close it in finally block and the same error occurred and the app crashes

[the image shows the error when the socket exception is thrown and unhandled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLE5u.png)

it catches the timeout exception as expected but then after another 10-15 seconds it throws an handled socket exception ,why it throws this socket exception and what can i do to avoid this?

Comment: But are you able to actually catch the exception in your try / catch? It seems I have the same error as you but for me, the error is only caught by VSCode (as per the image you linked)

Comment: @Gpack is right try your code at android studio it will work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement a timeout with the http package, here is how it can be done:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/io_client.dart' as http;

Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    final ioClient = HttpClient();
    client.connectionTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 5);
    final body = { 'email': email, 'password': password };
    final client = http.IOClient(ioClient);
    http.Response res;
    try {
      res = await client
        .post(
          '$url/login',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: jsonEncode(body));
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      // Display an alert, no internet
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
      return null;
    }

    // Do something with the response...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should consider using the HTTP package https://pub.dev/packages/http 
as it helps cleanup your code an helps with error handling.

Here's an example of a GET request using the package :

```
await http.get(url).then((response) async {
 // DO SOMETHING HERE
});
```

response.body is your data.
response.statusCode is your http status code (200, 404, 500, etc.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

and here's a post request with data :

```
var data = {
      "dataset1": {
        "key1": "value",
        "key2": "value",
      },
    };
await http.post(url,
  body: jsonEncode(data),
  headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}).then((response) async {
    // DO SOMETHING HERE
});
```

Comment: that's what i have already done , the part http.get() is from http package , the issue is the unhandled socket exception when i use timeout with the get method

Comment: Oops sorry! I didn't undestand your problem correctly !

Comment: that's okay , i you have any idea please share  it